# a function that chages the structure of a python list

Tags: python, string, list

I plan to write a python function that can change the structure of a list.
The input is:

```
list=[['A B C','D E F'],['1 2 3 ', '4 5 6 ']]
```

The output is:

```
list=[['A','B','C','D','E','F'],['1','2','3','4','5','6']]
```

I know I need the `split()` and `append()`. The confusing part is the loops.
Thanks so much!!

Comment: FYI, `list` is the function you use when you cast something to a list so be careful that you don't overwrite it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would advice you consider adding some code, even if it doesn't work, so that we can help you without doing everything for you (this site is not meant for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> my_list = [['A B C','D E F'],['1 2 3 ', '4 5 6 ']]
>>> map(lambda x:x.split(), map(" ".join, my_list))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the join method to join the contain elements in the nested lists. Then split at the spaces.

```
my_list = [['A B C', 'D E F'], ['1 2 3 ', '4 5 6']]
my_list = [' '.join(i).split() for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Look at the expected output, and look at your output, do they match?

Comment: I must have misinterpreted. I thought you were referring to an extra space in my final list.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's best not to over think it. Lets start with just one piece of your problem, `['A B C','D E F']` . You want to split each string, and put parts into a result list. Let's start by writing that function. You've correctly stated that this can be done using `split`/`append`, but lists also happen to have an `extend` method which will save you a few lines of code.

```
def as_char(seq):
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        result.extend(item.split())
    return result
```

Now you want to apply that function to every list in your input. For that you can use `map` for a list comprehension.

```
sample_input = [['A B C','D E F'],['1 2 3 ', '4 5 6 ']]
output = map(as_char, sample_input)
# or
output = [as_char(item) for item in sample_input]
```

Answer (score 2):

Join your subelements making sure to leave a space when joining then split on whitespace to split into individual elements and remove any trailing whitespace.

```
print([ " ".join(sub).split() for sub in l])
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```

If you only have two subelements unpack and split using str.format to allow a space between for splitting:

```
print([ "{} {}".format(a,b).split() for a,b in l ])

[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```

If you are using list as a variable name then don't as you will be shadowing the builtin list which often leads to more questions on SO...

Comment: That's nearly exactly what I did! And I'm racking up the downvotes.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, yours will have an extra space I imagine

Comment: Look at your first code block, then look at mine. And you're telling me I'm wrong?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, **YOU ARE WRONG**, did you get that?

Comment: lol two downvotes for a correct answer,some people really need to get out more

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I imagine you're being downvoted because you made the matter a lot harder than it needed to be. (For the record, I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo, you cannot help someone when they don't want to listen

Comment: Again Padraic, sorry for my difficulty. I honestly didn't see the space in the original question, as the code wasn't very well formatted. I don't really think Robin intended to put it there. I think it was just a mistyping.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, don't worry about it, I was trying to help you originally by pointing out there was an extra element in your output. I had not downvoted you either and to be honest until you commented on mine I had not even looked at another answer. I was always going to use just join I just pasted the wrong code originally.